# Cat pees in the same spot. What can I do?

Tags: cats

My indoor-only neutered male adult cat is always peeing in the same spot. I've tried all kinds of litter boxes, and he pees and poops in the box, but he's now getting into this habit of peeing in a very specific spot in the apartment.

Is there something (a product or a mixture) that I can spray in the area so that he stops peeing there?

Or are there any plants that I can put there?

I'm including a pictute of my cat's pee. Someone asked me if he was spraying, and I don't think he is. It's a puddle on the floor, and the odd thing is that there's a small crack on the floor next to where he pees:

As you can see, I've clearly identified the urine.
 [image]

Comment: Please clarify: is he actually urinating (puddle under the belly) or spraying (puddle behind his body, preferably on vertical surfaces)? Also: have you tried putting his litter box directly on the spot?

Comment: I've included a picture. I've never seen him pee, but I don't think he's spraying.