# Cat pees on carpet and blankets, how can I stop this?

Tags: cats, behavior, health

Back in may my cat had kittens. We kept two. One of the kittens, the male one, uses the litter box like a champ, while the female one pees on blankets and the carpet.She has also started peeing on trash bags!  We have tried switching litter, odor free litter, cleaning the spots where she has urinated, taken the blankets she urinated on outside for her to pee on, and taken her to the vet, and they say there is nothing wrong! We have also kept the house ESPECIALLY clean since this has happened.But nothing has worked and she still does this! Just recently she peed under our Christmas tree and that was the final straw for my mom. I really don’t want to give her up but I don’t want my house smelling like pee. Can someone please help! :)

Comment: Welcome to pets:SE :) Your question has already answers in a lots of spots here. Have a look at this question and answers first: https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/21436/cat-pees-in-the-same-spot-what-can-i-do it is a good start for more research